# SSRS Web page(Hope Page) is Blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have installed SSRS 2014 and Configured. When I open the web link from *Report Server Configuration Manager* I get below message,

[image]

I can't see any home page. I am not sure what is missing.

[image]

Comment: try http://<ComputerName>/reports

Comment: @newguy When I try that it gives, HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable error

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for the report manager is
`http://<Server Name>/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=List`

Comment: When I try that it gives, HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable error

Comment: @user2331670  Can you please post a screenshot of that?

Comment: I have added to my question

Comment: @user2331670  This usually means the SSRS Service is not running.  Have a google for "SSRS Report Manager 503 Error"

Answer (score 0):

Have you solve it yet?
It might happen because the reporting service is not running-make sure the service is running ( can check at sql server config manager) screenshots added.

You can also refresh the service from command prompt by typing:
net stop reporting service
and 
net start reporting service
[Sql Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtT8n.jpg)

Comment: solved it by creating new Reporting server database through Report Service  Manager